# Run an App on windows tablet without uploading to store

Tags: windows-8

I have made a windows 8 app and do not want to upload it on store. Without uploading the app on the app store how I can share my app on a windows tablet. Should I use the xap file and run it or how can I run the App on my friends window tablet, any ideas or suggestions of how I can share the same.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app via a [remote debugging monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx). How you can do this is described here:
[Remote Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx)

Or you can setup a [beta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) version for your app.

[Beta Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need a sideloading key from MS or install the app as a developer using powershell. This was helpful to my company when we had to release a window 8.1 application without using the store.

http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2013/04/30/how-to-create-a-windows-store-app-side-loading-install/

See also:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx#SideloadingRequirements